# Debug javascript of firefox addon

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon

I am working on a firefox addon which is heavily built on javascript. Addon is a ui recorder which has a popup window consisting of the addon specific buttons operating on a tab of main window.

When I inspect the debugger of either of the wondows, I dont see the javascript of the addon to set breakpoint or inspect. How do I debug?

[image]

Note: I want to debug the addon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to break point in your addon code? try this addon [Tiny JavaScript Debugger](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tiny-javascript-debugger/)

Answer (score 3):

here's a MUCH better solution its made my mozilla itself its added to firefox in ff31:

https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/04/08/add-on-debugger-now-in-firefox-nightly/

watch that video

Answer (score 2):

you have to use browser console (ctrl+shift+j) and eanable the develoment prefs ([see mdn for prefs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Setting_up_extension_development_environment?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Setting_up_extension_development_environment#Development_preferences))

Comment: I did that but to of no use.

Comment: You aren't getting any error messages?  [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console)

Comment: I am getting error messages in web console but I want to inspect the execution which cannot be done with just web console. Interestingly David stark says "FF fails to grab the javascript even when you tell it you want to do chrome debugging". in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/se-builder/8rPeOBwGxCA

Comment: oh i think i got you, you want to break point in your addon code? try this addon [Tiny JavaScript Debugger](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tiny-javascript-debugger/)

Comment: If you think my original question is detailed enough to not need any edit, can you add your comment to your answer. I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DevPrefs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/devprefs/) in conjunction with the current debugger